# endBackgroundTask without the background identifier

Tags: ios, multithreading, background, crash

I'm using a library which is closed source that is starting a background task and I don't have the background task identifier...

...anyone got any bright ideas on how I could end this background task ?

It is always running to completion and I often get crash reports like this:

```
    Application Specific Information:
 THEAPP[245] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
  {(
    <SBProcessAssertion: 0xee35590> identifier: UIKitBackgroundCompletionTask process:  THEAPP[245] permittedBackgroundDuration: 600.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:245  preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep ,
     <SBProcessAssertion: 0xeed2a60> identifier: UIKitBackgroundCompletionTask process:  THEAPP[245] permittedBackgroundDuration: 600.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:245  preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep ,
     <SBProcessAssertion: 0xee24f00> identifier: UIKitBackgroundCompletionTask process: THEAPP[245] permittedBackgroundDuration: 600.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:245 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep 
 )}
```

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a library bug that needs to be fixed in the library.  I don't know any way to get that task id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in the library, and I got a later version with a fix. There didn't seem to be a way end that task.